# can Asp.net get parent window url by referrer?

Tags: asp.net

i heard that , if your asp.net page is inside a iframe, and u want to get the parent url, you can achieve this by using the referrer?

i tested is okay, and found that the window parent url will included in the referrer when called the iframe content

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Assume that i can only use server side to achieve

I just want to ask is that way safe?

Any chance to lost the referrer url in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The browser is not guaranteed to send the referer. It's all up to the browser/configuration/extensions/proxies and whatnot between the request and your server.
2. If the user navigates to a different page within the iframe, the referer will point to whatever the user came from.

All in all, never use the referer for any logic that may fail if it's not there or if it has an unexpected value.

Comment: so is there any solution to get the parent url, assume not asking client (parent page owner) to pass any param to the iframe src

Comment: @user1923444: Nope, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but it is not entirely in ASP.Net.

You would have to get the referrer from Javascript and pass that to the iFrame.

One of the 2 following calls would be what you are looking for.

```
top.document.referrer
```

or

```
parent.document.referrer
```